# Extend multiple interfaces with Zod

Tags: typescript, zod

With typescript, I can implement multiple interfaces

```
interface Name {
 name: string
}

interface Age {
 age: number
}

interface People extends Name, Age {
 height: number
}
```

How could I do the same thing with Zod?

What I did

```
const nameZ = z.object({ name: z.string() })
const ageZ = z.object({ age: z.number() })

const peopleZ = z.object({ hieght: z.number }).merge(nameZ).merge(ageZ)
```

However, it looks quite ugly and hard to read. Any other solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options. The [`.extend` method](https://zod.dev/?id=extend) exists, so you can use that as the last chained method which avoids you needing to type `z.object( )`. The other option you have is to change the order of merges. If there were a significant amount of schemas you wanted to merge, you could write a function, however you'd lose TypeScript type information unless you figure out a way to do it.

```
import { z } from "zod";

const nameZ = z.object({ name: z.string() })
const ageZ = z.object({ age: z.number() })

const peopleZ  = z.object({ height: z.number() }).merge(nameZ).merge(ageZ)
const peopleZ2 = nameZ.merge(ageZ).extend({ height: z.number() })
const peopleZ3 = nameZ.merge(ageZ).merge(z.object({ height: z.number() }))
```

https://tsplay.dev/m3vejN